# Можно ли передать jumbo-кадр в сети Ethernet?

Tags: сеть, администрирование, tcp-ip, ethernet, mtu

Я тут задумался, как можно передать jumbo кадр 9000 байт, если ethernet поддерживает до 1500. Эта технология не имеет смысла, т.к. они в любом случае будут дробиться?

Answer (score 4):

Можно, если всё сетевое оборудование (начиная от железа (сетевые карты, коммутаторы) и ПО (ОС, драйвера сетевых карт, прошивки цисок) по пути от начальной точки до конечной будут поддерживать jumbo-фреймы.

Если вас интересует настройка под конкретное оборудование, то гуглите что-то типа "как включить Jumbo frame для Windows Server 2012" и похожие запросы.

Что будет происходить в случае если где-то посередине технология не поддерживается -- сильно зависит от конкретного оборудования, вплоть до полного отбрасывания пакета.

Вам вряд ли есть смысл заниматься таким между произвольными узлами в интернете (вы не сможете контролировать инфраструктуру), но если у вас два сервера в стойке соединены отдельным линком -- можно выжать 3% - 5%. Это немного, почти на пределе стат. погрешности.

Comment: На фибре между стойками выжимается побольше, но всё равно не больше 12%.

Comment: Я только не пойму.  MTU 1500 - это некий стандарт или просто возможности сетевой карты (типа не более 1500)? А Джамбо кадр - это типа отклонение от стандарта?